# Laravel Eloquent rather complex relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have two tables, users and jobs. A user owns a job:

from User model:

```php
public function getJobs(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Jobs','operative_id','id');
}

public function getIncompleteJobs(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Jobs','operative_id','id')
    ->where('jobStatus_id', '=', 1);
}
```

This is fine but the job has a status (completed, pending etc) in a field called 'status_id' and I want to further refine getJobs() so it only returns those with status_id equalling 2.

May be I am being thick!

Edit from the comments:

```php
$op = App\User::where('client_id', $us->getCompany->id)
    ->where('operative', 1)
    ->orderby('name')
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->with('getIncompleteJobs')
    ->get();
```

Comment: You should be able to append a `->where('status_id', '=', 2);` to your `->belongsTo()`; see if that works.

Comment: `->where('jobStatus_id', '=', 1);` should that be `status_id`?

Comment: Another thing; `jobs` (`getJobs()` and `getIncompleteJobs()`) suggests that many results will be returned, but you're only returning 1 (`belongsTo()` returns a single record or `null`), and your model name `App\Jobs` should be singular `Job`... Check your naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the relationship, and them call it with whatever condition you want in another method.

Like that:

```
public function jobs()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Jobs','operative_id','id');
}

public function completedJobs()
{
    return $this->jobs()->where('status_id', '=', 2);
}
```

Comment: It seems that the relationship is always null. Perhaps this is better with a raw sql, but eloquent is neater.

Comment: You can't use `->get()` in a relationship, otherwise calling `->with('completedJobs')` will return an error. (it expects a `Builder` class, `->get()` converts it to a `Collection`)

Comment: @TimLewis I have forgotten to add `->get()` on the first place, but I edited it later. But thanks for the reminder, anyway. :)

Comment: Sorry the get was typo by me. There is no get.

Comment: Yeah, this will work if you call `User::first()->completedJobs();` (with the `()`), but breaks the ability to use as an attribute (`User::first()->completedJobs;`) or eager load (`->with("completedJobs")`) or append conditions (`User::first()->completedJobs()->where(...);`)

Comment: There could be many results. I tried adding get() but got an error "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::addEagerConstraints does not exist."

Comment: "*otherwise calling ->with('completedJobs') will return an error.* [...] *Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::addEagerConstraints does not exist.*" - That's the error I'm talking about. Don't use `->get()`.

Comment: @TimLewis you could just change the method to `getCompletedJobs()` in order to use it as an attribute, couldn't you?

Comment: Adding `()` makes it a method, not an attribute. `->getCompletedJobs` vs `->getCompletedJobs()`. Just remove the `->get()`. You want `->getComepletedJobs()` to return a `Builder` so you can continue to add clauses onto it, and Laravel magically converts a `Builder` to a `Collection` if you use `->getComepletedJobs`, but not if it is already one.

Comment: No problem. I feel like your solution should work, but I think there's deeper issues with the relationship as a whole; see my comment on naming conventions on the actual question; I don't know if `belongsTo()` is the right relationship to be using here, `jobs` suggests that a `User` would have many `Job`s, etc.